# Button above image with zoom objective c

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uibutton, zooming

I need to show an image, and above it some buttons that correspond to certain clickable areas of the image, the problem is that the image has zoom, and when i zoom the image, the buttons do not stay in the same place as the picture. The solution was to use the class ImageScrolView, used in the example of Apple PhotoScroller. The button appears exactly in the right place, regardless of zoom.

Just like the example, i use a ScrollView to display multiple images, these images are shown by class ImageScrollView.

This class declares one UIView in the .H file, but in the implementation file, the method that displays the image, convert the UIView into a UIImageView

```
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: image];
```

then create my button and add to the imageView.

```
 amazon = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
 amazonia.frame = CGRectMake (92,240,109,142);
 [amazon addTarget: self action: @ selector (selectState :) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
 [imageView addSubview: amazon];
```

My problem is that the button does not respond to button events, it appears in the right place and everything, but does not respond to button events.

Any ideas? Ideias on how to implement those clickable areas on the image are welcome too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure to set `imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES`!

Hope that helps.